# Particularly well-behaved functions: the gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Im going through Bracewell: Fourier Transform and its Applications and I'm struggling with one part in particular (Chapter 5 the impluse symbol: pg 89-90 2nd ed).

$\textbf{Definition}$

Consider the class S of functions which possess derivatives of all orders at all points and which together with all the derivatives, die off at least as rapidly as $|x|^{-N}$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, no matter how large $N$ may be. Members of this class are called $\textit{particularly well-behaved functions}$.

I'm struggling to show that the Gaussian is particularly well behaved:

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi \tau}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\tau}}.$

In the book he goes about showing the Fourier transform ($\mathscr{F}(s)$, say) of a particularly well-behaved function (call it $F(x)$) is particularly well behaved by differentiating $\mathscr{F}(s)$ $p$ times and then integrating by parts $N$ times and showing that $|\mathscr{F}(s)|\leq \frac{(2\pi)^{p-N}}{|s|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\frac{d^N}{dx^N}[x^pF(x)]|dx=O(|s|^{-N})$.

I've tried methods like that but have had no luck, any help would be great.

Comment: You an turn one into the other by defining $y=2\sqrt \tau x$, so the problems are the same.  The fundamental result you need is that $e^{-x^2}p(x) \to 0$ for any polynomial $p(x)$.  Have you seen that?

Comment: Ok, let me edit the question.

Comment: As @RossMillikan said before, $e^{-x^{2}}p(x) \to 0$ for any polynomial $p(x)$ when $x \to \infty$. This follows from L'Hospital. Besided, you can use that composite of differentiable functions are also differentiable.

Comment: @Ross Millikan apologies but I haven't come across that before so I'm not sure how the details of that argument would work.

Comment: @Willy.K couldn't notify two people in one comment!

Comment: Once you have that theorem, and I do not remember how it is proved, you just say that all the derivatives of $e^{-x^2}$ are of the form $e^{-x^2}p(x)$ and your factor $x^N$ just changes one polynomial into another.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok, so I'm comfortable with $e^{-x^2}p(x)\rightarrow 0$. But how do you adapt a proof that shows it goes to zero to one showing its bounded above by $|x|^{-N}$ for any $N$?

Comment: Given $N$, you can compare $p(x)x^N$, which is just another polynomial, with $e^{-x^2}$.  As that ratio goes to zero, divide by $p(x)$ and you are done.